# creating multiple df rows based on two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have a df comprised of power outages with several columns, a start date column, and an end date column

what i would like to be able to do:

1. scan the "start date" column for the earliest date
2. scan the "finish date" column for the latest date
3. build a date index with all dates in between those two dates
4. for each row, create a row for each date from the start date to the finish date, thus removing the need for both date columns

so if my df looked as follows:

```
start date    mw outage    end date     location
01/01/2000    1000         01/04/2000   merica
01/01/2000    2000         01/03/2000   canadia
```

i'd want it instead to look like this

```
date        mw outage       location
01/01/2000  1000            merica
01/01/2000  2000            canadia
01/02/2000  1000            merica
01/02/2000  2000            canadia
01/03/2000  1000            merica
01/03/2000  2000            canadia
01/04/2000  1000            merica
```

i think i can use reindex to add the missing dates but i'm not sure how to identify the oldest/newest and i don't know how to create the rows in this manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need create the range date column then `explode`

```
df.startdate=pd.to_datetime(df.startdate)
df.enddate=pd.to_datetime(df.enddate)
df['date']=[pd.date_range(x, y ) for x , y in zip(df.startdate, df.enddate)]
df=df.explode('date')
Out[169]: 
   startdate  mwoutage    enddate location       date
0 2000-01-01      1000 2000-01-04   merica 2000-01-01
0 2000-01-01      1000 2000-01-04   merica 2000-01-02
0 2000-01-01      1000 2000-01-04   merica 2000-01-03
0 2000-01-01      1000 2000-01-04   merica 2000-01-04
1 2000-01-01      2000 2000-01-03  canadia 2000-01-01
1 2000-01-01      2000 2000-01-03  canadia 2000-01-02
1 2000-01-01      2000 2000-01-03  canadia 2000-01-03
```

Comment: So sorry for the late reply here - this was a fantastic solution. If I were to want to fill dates without outages as an entry but with the mwoutage as 0, is that something that would greatly add to the complexity of this?